# how i get querySelectorAll html elements in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, virtual-dom

I am using react with functional component. I also use react-bootstrap , I attached the react-bootstrap carousel , everything is fine with react-bootstrap, for some functionality, I want to get three divs in react , divs has same classes. I know if I use simple html css js then I easily do that,

`querySelectorAll(".indicator-btn")`

but i want this on react. How can I do that? please suggest me a best practices for that.

This is a my component , in the last i have three divs which i want for Dom.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Cardcarousel from "./Cardcarousel";
import { Carousel } from "react-bootstrap";
import Brand1img from "../images/brand1.png";
import Airbnbimg from "../images/Airbnb.png";
import Microsoft from "../images/microsoft.png";
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

function Carouselx() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleSelect = (selectedIndex, e) => {
    console.log(selectedIndex, "e=>", e);
    setIndex(selectedIndex);
  };

  const isSlide = (slide) => {
    console.log("slide no => " + slide);
    console.log(this);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="px-5 py-3">
        <Carousel activeIndex={index} onSelect={handleSelect} onSlide={isSlide}>
          <Carousel.Item>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <Cardcarousel
                  name="Technology UI/UX"
                  companylogo={Brand1img}
                  type="Full time job"
                />
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <Cardcarousel
                  name="Technology Backend developer"
                  companylogo={Airbnbimg}
                  type="Part time job"
                />
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <Cardcarousel
                  name="Technology Backend developer"
                  companylogo={Microsoft}
                  type="Internee"
                />
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Carousel.Item>
          <Carousel.Item>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <Cardcarousel
                  name="Technology UI/UX"
                  companylogo={Brand1img}
                  type="Full time job"
                />
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <Cardcarousel
                  name="Technology Backend developer"
                  companylogo={Airbnbimg}
                  type="Part time job"
                />
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <Cardcarousel
                  name="Technology front end developer"
                  companylogo={Microsoft}
                  type="Internee"
                />
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Carousel.Item>
        </Carousel>
        <div className="carusel-indecator-container">
          <div className="indicator-btn indicator-btn1"></div>
          <div className="indicator-btn indicator-btn2"></div>
          <div className="indicator-btn indicator-btn3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Carouselx;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `useState` to get its refs (also `useRef` but there'll be a lot more inconveniences potentially).

```
const [btn1, setBtn1] = useState();
const [btn2, setBtn2] = useState();
const [btn3, setBtn3] = useState();

...

<div ref={setBtn1} className="indicator-btn indicator-btn1"></div>
<div ref={setBtn2} className="indicator-btn indicator-btn2"></div>
<div ref={setBtn3} className="indicator-btn indicator-btn3"></div>
```

At some point (after 1st rendering) you'll have btn1, btn2, btn3 as button elements. If you want to use it, assumingly imperatively, you could useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!btn1 || !btn2 || !btn3) return;
  // do something with these refs i.e. make them jquery! $(btn1)
}, [btn1, btn2, btn3]);
```

Comment: , Thanks it working and I understand also. I just need one clarification. You told me do not use useRef() , and you pass a ref={} on a button. so ref is not same as  useRef(), or ref means useRef , or its a special attributes in react?

Comment: `useRef` is a hook like `useState` that is surprisingly not always fit for use with the `ref=` attribute, contrary to its name.